# Convert char array to a string with cin.getline(.)

Tags: c++, string, oop, char

hi guys so my question is how to convert a char array to a string. here is my code:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    while (true) {
        char lol[128];
        cout << "you say >> ";
        cin.getline(lol,256);
        cout << lol << endl;;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

so I want to convert lol to a string variable like "stringedChar" (if thats even english lol)
so I can do stuff like:

```cpp
        string badwords[2] = {"frick","stupid"};
        for (int counter = 0; counter < 2;counter++) {
            if(strigedChar == badwords[counter]) {
             bool isKicked = true;
             cout << "Inappropriate message!\n";
            }
        }
```

Sorry im just a c++ begginer lol

Comment: Why not use a string from the beginning `string lol; getline(cin, lol);` Simple no?

Comment: But if for some reason you really need to convert, then it's not hard, `string stringedChar = lol;`

Comment: Would also fix the error of reading 256 characters into a 128 character array

Comment: Also, make `badwords` a `std::set<std::string>` and then you can just test `badwords.count(lol) != 0`.

Comment: doesnt work for me. also does it ignore whitespace? like it wont stop storing stuff when it sees a whitespace

Comment: when i do getline(cin,lol); it says error

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? getline works the same way whether you are reading into a char array or a string. The only difference being that input will be terminated when the char array is full, but that's not an issue with a string.

Comment: oh it worked now ty

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this :

as char lol[128];
into string like: std::string str(lol);

Line : cin.getline(lol,256); <--> should be changed to cin.getline(lol,128)

Answer (score 0):

Just invoke `std::getline()` on a `std::string` object instead of messing about with a `char` array, and use `std::set<std::string>` for `badwords` as testing set membership is trivial:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>

static std::set<std::string> badwords{
    "frick",
    "stupid"
};

int main() {
    std::string line;

    while (std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
        if (badwords.count(line) != 0) {
            std::cout << "Inappropriate message!\n";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note that this tests whether the entire line is equal to any element of the set, *not* that the line contains any element of the set, but your code appears to be attempting to do the former anyway.

Comment: In C++20, `std::set` has a new `contains()` method: `if (badwords.contains(line))`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, I saw that but it's not available everywhere yet and is unlikely to have significantly different performance characteristics.

Comment: true, but I'm just mentioning it for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you have a mistake in your code.  You are allocating an array of 128 `char`s, but you are telling `cin.getline()` that you allocated 256 `char`s.  So you have a buffer overflow waiting to happen.

That said, `std::string` has constructors that accept `char[]` data as input, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    while (true) {
        char lol[128];
        cout << "you say >> ";
        cin.getline(lol, 128);
        string s(lol, cin.gcount());
        cout << s << endl;;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, you really should use `std::getline()` instead, which populates a `std::string` instead of a `char[]`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    while (true) {
        string lol;
        cout << "you say >> ";
        getline(cin, lol);
        cout << lol << endl;;
    }
    return 0;
}
```